# php: parse string to get string

Tags: php, string

How would I extract the number `33` before the underscore in the following?

```
33_restoffilename.txt.
```

would something like following work?

```
int strPos = strpos("33_filename.txt", "_");
str num = substr ("33_filename.txt" , 0 , strPos );
```

Comment: *would something like following work?* Have you tried it? (Also see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php + php is not strictly typed, so `int, str` isn't valid PHP)

Comment: A variable in php is $var, so make int strPos $strPost and str num $num

Comment: if the num always at the beginning, `strstr($string, "_", true);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are may way to achive this:

**Method 1:**

```
$strPos = strpos("33_filename.txt", "_");
echo $num = substr("33_filename.txt" , 0 , $strPos );
```

**Method 2:**

```
$str = '33_filename.txt';
$str_arr = explode('_', $str);
echo $num = $str_arr[0];
```

Comment: Ok.  Method 1 did the trick. Thanks to you and also Ben and others!

Answer (score 3):

If the naming convention is always `number_filename.ext`, you can use `explode()`:

```
//Put the filename into the variable $name
$name = "33_restoffilename.txt";

//Split the name by "_"
$parts = explode("_", $name);

//Get the first part of the name from the array (position 1)
$number = $parts[0];

//Output
echo $number;
```

This will output

> 33

Answer (score 1):

Use [strstr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php).

```
$str = '33_filename.txt';
$num = strstr($str, '_', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method - 1**

```
$getIntegerFromBeginning = substr($string, 0, strspn($string, "0123456789"));
echo $getIntegerFromBeginning;
```

**Method - 2**

```
$getIntegerFromBeginning = explode("_", $string, 2);
echo  $getIntegerFromBeginning[0];
```

Replace $string with exact string.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$string = '33_filename.txt';

$arrString = explode('_', $string);

echo $value = $arrString[0]; //Will output 33
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really very simple we don't need these string functions in this case. Just do type casting and you will get integer number. It will be fast and easy

```
$pp='33_restoffilename.txt';
echo (int)$pp;
```

No need to make it complicated